# Keycloak Authorization Services for dozens of resources which belong to dozens of users

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, permissions, authorization, keycloak

I'm currently trying to figure out if the [Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/) provided by the Keycloak Authorization Server is the thing what I need to secure my application.

So I have a Python Rest API which has (to keep it simple) job objects that can be created, modified, deleted, etc. (usual CRUD stuff).
Up until now the API was completely unprotected and we need some Auth before it can go live.
I decided to go with Keycloak as it was already setup in our company and hooked up backend and fronted to the authorization server using the OAuth2 authorization code flow and OIDC.

So now the user can login to the web-app client and use the access token afterwards to do things with the Python backend.
The authorization process works fine, the token gets validated and I even figured out, how to acquire scopes and verify them in the backend.

Now i read about this Authorization Services thing and I am wondering if I can use it to control/ map which job belongs to which (Keycloak) user. Like this:

```
/api/job/job-nr-1   <-> user-id-5 (create, delete, etc)
/api/job/job-nr-1   <-> user-id-1 (read-only)
/api/job/job-nr-2   <-> user-id-3 
...
```

If I understand it correctly, each Job would be a resource and the things that users can do (create, delete, etc) would be scopes.

But is it practically possible to map each job to one user?
Do I need to setup a policy for each job <-> user relationship to allow one (and only one) user to edit this job?
And can this be done via the API? The jobs are created dynamically, so I can't do this myself via the Admin UI.

This all sounds pretty much work and I wonder if Keycloak is the right place to manage this or if I should rather setup a separate database for those permissions/ relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic authorization almost always involves using claims in addition to scopes:

**YOUR SCENARIO**

It feels like you need properties / claims similar to the following to implement your authorization, and some of these are domain specific and could change often:

- User ID
- Role(s)
- Permissions associated to the role(s)

**DESIGN YOUR SCOPES**

Scopes are high level static values, such as 'jobs_read' and 'jobs_write'. They represent an area of data and allowed operations on that data.

**DESIGN YOUR CLAIMS**

Claims are runtime values, such as permissions the user has, that are looked up after the user has authenticated.

**MANAGING CLAIMS**

Store the data in the right places, and you will then be more easily able to change things over time:

- Generic identity data should be stored in Keycloak
- Domain specific / volatile data should be stored in your business data

**AUTHORIZATION**

There are two techniques here:

- Reach out from the Authorization Server when tokens are issued, to get claims from the business data and include them in access tokens
- If the first option is not possible then look the values up in the API based on the User ID in the access token

**DOCS**

At Curity we like to explain the science of this - in a way that will work for any provider - see [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) for a worked example.

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer. I will read through the article tomorrow and look if it's possible with Keycloak to get those claims directly from the AS.

I'm not quite sure how to store those claims correctly in my business database, but maybe the article explains it too.

Comment: Cool - I would say it depends on the complexity of the rules. People sometimes start out with all rules in the Authorization Server - or sometimes add tables such as Roles and Permissions to their own data. Neither is wrong - the solution chosen often depends on how complex the rules are, and whether you feel multiple apps will conflict with each other. But it is worth at least being aware of the logical separation between identity data and business data.